Semisimple elements and fixed points
The following statement seems to be well-known:

Let $X$ be a variety on which an affine algebraic group $H$ acts with
finitely many orbits and let $s \in H$ be semisimple. Then $H_s = \{h
 \in H \mid hsh^{-1}= s \}$ has only finitely many orbits in $X^s = \{ x \in
 X \mid sx =x \}$.

For example, this is stated without proof in a paper of Spaltenstein (see the last page of [1]). A similar result is mentioned in the Chriss–Ginzburg book [2, Prop. 8.1.17]. However, their proof uses at some point that for $x \in X$ any semisimple element in $H_x = \{h \in H \mid hx = x \}$ lies in a maximal torus of $H_x$. This seems incorrect given that the stabilizer $H_x$ could be disconnected. A similar argument avoiding this issue is given in [3, §5.4] which instead uses the following statement without proof:

A semisimple class of an algebraic group meets a closed subgroup in a union of finitely many semisimple classes of that subgroup.

For certain groups and under some restrictions on the characteristic, this can be deduced from results of Richardson (see for example [4, §3.8]) but this argument doesn't seem to apply in the general setting.
Is there a good reference or a simple proof for either of these two statements that makes no restriction on the algebraic group or the characteristic of the field?

[1] Spaltenstein, N. "On unipotent and nilpotent elements of groups of type $E_6$." Journal of the London Mathematical Society 2.3 (1983): 413–420.
[2] Chriss, Neil, and Victor Ginzburg. Representation theory and complex geometry. Birkhäuser, 1997.
[3] Kazhdan, David, and George Lusztig. "Proof of the Deligne–Langlands conjecture for Hecke algebras." Inventiones mathematicae 87 (1987): 153–215.
[4] Humphreys, James E. Conjugacy classes in semisimple algebraic groups. American Mathematical Soc., 1995.

See Lemma 1.10 in Popov–Vinberg, Invariant Theory, recalled in this answer. In fact, the proof below is almost identical to the last paragraph of that answer.
To prove your first displayed statement, Lemma 1.10 shows that it is enough to show that for every $x \in X^s(k)$, we have $\mathfrak{h}(x) \cap \mathrm{T}_x(X^s) = \mathfrak{h}_s(x)$, where $\mathfrak{h}(x)$ is the image of the differential at the identity of the orbit map $\alpha\colon H \to X$ through $x$, etc. So let $h \in \mathfrak{h}$ and suppose $\mathrm{d}\alpha(h) \in \mathrm{T}_x(X^s) = \mathrm{T}_x(X)^{s=1}$. Write $h = \sum_c h_c$, where $c$ ranges over $k^\times$ and $s(h_c) = ch_c$, and note that $\mathrm{d}\alpha(h) = \sum_c \mathrm{d}\alpha(h_c)$. We have $s(\mathrm{d}\alpha(h_c)) = c\mathrm{d}\alpha(h_c)$, so $\mathrm{d}\alpha(h_c) \in \mathrm{T}_x(X)^{s = c}$. Since $T_x(X) = \bigoplus_c T_x(X)^{s=c}$, it follows that $\mathrm{d}\alpha(h_c) = 0$ for all $c \neq 1$ and thus $\mathrm{d}\alpha(h) = \mathrm{d}\alpha(h_1) \in \mathfrak{h}_s(x)$.
EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, for the lemma in Popov-Vinberg to apply, it is necessary to know that the orbit map $H \to H \cdot x$ is surjective on tangent spaces. We now show how to reduce to this case.
First, we may assume $k = \overline{k}$. Passing from $H$ to $H_{\mathrm{red}}$, we may assume that $H$ is smooth (as this passage does not affect the number of orbits). Since there are only finitely many $H$-orbits in $X$, we may pass from $X$ to a single one of these to assume that $H$ acts transitively on $X$. If $x \in X(k)$ and $H_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$ in $H$, then $X \cong H/H_x$. Let $\widetilde{X} = H/(H_x)_{\mathrm{red}}$, so there is an $H$-equivariant homeomorphism $\pi\colon \widetilde{X} \to X$. In particular, the map $\widetilde{X}^s \to X^s$ is also an $H_s$-equivariant homomeomorphism, so we may pass from $X$ to $\widetilde{X}$ to assume that $H_x$ is smooth, and hence the orbit map $H \to H \cdot x$ is surjective on tangent spaces, as desired.

That's a very nice answer, thank you! However, Popov-Vinberg seem to be working under the assumption that $char(k) = 0$. For example, they use that the orbit map $\alpha_x: H \rightarrow H \cdot x$ is surjective on tangent spaces. Spaltenstein claims (and uses) the result also in positive characteristic. Is there a similar argument one can use in positive characteristic?

OK, good point. I believe that the assumption $\mathrm{char}(k) = 0$ is only used to show that $\alpha_x$ is surjective on tangent spaces (see the linked answer), so I have edited to explain how to reduce to this case.

Perfect, I think this works in the generality I am looking for. I also just found another paper of Richardson which seems to be using the exact same trick to handle the positive characteristic setting in case someone needs a reference:
Richardson, Roger W. "On orbits of algebraic groups and Lie groups." Bulletin of the Australian Mathematical Society 25.1 (1982): 1-28.

Link to the article @jba referenced: Richardson - On orbits of algebraic groups and Lie groups.  Richardson is one of those authors where I discovered his work only late, but it always seems to have new and pleasant surprises.
